# Is it possible for Qvalidator to show a popup

Tags: c++, qt

I wanted to know if its possible for QValidator to show a Popup box incase a QlineEdit item is invalid. I know that Qvalidator simply filters the input and only displays the data if its valid. However I want it to display the data that I type in and display a tooltip (popup box) incase the input is invalid.

Comment: I would try to subclass `QValidator` and override its `validate` method. Inside `validate`, call `validate` from the superclass and if it returns *invalid*, you can perform any specific action like emitting some signal which then shows your popup. Maybe you can also connect to the `changed` signal of `QValidator`, but it seems that you need to revalidate the input then to get the current validation state

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass the specific validator you want to use and override its `validate` method, so that it emits a signal after validation. For example, for a `QIntValidator`, you could create a sub class as follows (code only showing the relevant excerpts):

**Header file:**

```
class QIntValidatorReporter : public QIntValidator {
   Q_OBJECT;

public:
   QIntValidatorReporter(int minimum, int maximum, QObject * parent = 0);

   virtual QValidator::State validate(QString& input, int& pos ) const;

signals:
   void setError(const QString& msg) const;
};
```

**.cpp file:**

```
QValidator::State QIntValidatorReporter::validate(QString& input, int& pos ) const {
   QValidator::State result = QIntValidator::validate(input, pos);

   if (result == QValidator::Invalid) {
      emit setError(QString("Allowed range: %1 to %2").arg(bottom()).arg(top()));
   } else {
      emit setError("");
   }

   return result;
}
```

By connecting the `setError` signal to any slot as required, you can implement your required functionality to report the validation state.

See https://github.com/afester/StackOverflow/tree/master/Qt/QValidator for a complete sample project.